# Is gambling hereditary?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

I heard that gambling tendencies may be inherited from parents. I am not sure about that so I posted this question. Is that true? Has any researches been done on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be to some extent, for example, because gambling behaviour is mediated by traits like impulsiveness {1,2} which are heritable {3}.

**References**

{1} Steel, Z. and A. Blaszczynski (1998). "Impulsivity, personality disorders and pathological gambling severity." Addiction 93(6): 895-905.

{2} Michalczuk, R., et al. (2011). "Impulsivity and cognitive distortions in pathological gamblers attending the UK National Problem Gambling Clinic: a preliminary report." Psychological Medicine 41(12): 2625-2635.

{3} Bezdjian, S., et al. (2011). "Genetic and environmental influences on impulsivity: A meta-analysis of twin, family and adoption studies." Clinical psychology review 31(7): 1209-1223.

Comment: Got to it before me, I was going to use this reference which is a really good twin study on GA http://archpsyc.jamanetwork.com/article.aspx?articleid=210812

Answer (score 0):

Besides any brain markers that might say "yes", there is a huge amount of influence on upbringing. How parents behave and the way they look at "chance/risk" in life can affect how a child might be raised. Addictive personalities breed addictive traights in others such as overeating.